# conflict select with EJB3

Tags: java, orm, jpa

Today i have new problem with JPA/EJB3. I have 2 table `User` and `Group`
with mapping `OneToMany` (Group One - User Many)

When I use select statement in EJB, for example:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Iuser.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM Iuser i")
```

a conflict occur, it not know `group` field I choose where table? (`group` field in `User` Table is `groupid` [foreign key] and `group` field in `Group` table is `Group` [Primary Key])

How can i solve this problem?

I know user `user.group` button statement in EJB3 not execute, please help.

Comment: I'm sorry I tried to understand the question... but didn't succeed. What is the conflict you're talking about? Do you get an error message? Can you provide it? Can you also provide the mapped entities?

Comment: thankyou for responded my question is User Table have one field with name iGroup it is Foreign key of Table Group .!!! their relationship are many to one - Table user (Many) -- Table Group (one) it mean one group can have many users join one group!. and when i use Entitymanager.createNameQuery("User.findAll") when i run it error occur with Error code 1064. such as you write SQL script as Select group from user it would occur Error Code 1064 , but i used Select u.group from user u, it work well

Comment: i want advise from people, how to solved it ?, and now i have new problem it is: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /test.xhtml @24,173 value="#{userController.users.username}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null! please help me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bet is that the `IGroup` entity is mapped on the table `Group` which is a reserved keyword and might cause problems if not escaped.

If you're using a JPA 2.0 provider, you can tell the JPA provider to escape the database object name by enclosing the name within double quotes, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"GROUP\"")
public class IGroup {
    ...
}
```

If you're using JPA 1.0, there is no standardized way, it depends on the JPA provider. With Hibernate, you'd have to use backticks:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="`GROUP`")
public class IGroup {
    ...
}
```

Or, change the table name for a non reserved keyword:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="GROUPS")
public class IGroup {
    ...
}
```

Does it make sense?